# Where is the ib_logfile?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have to take a cold backup of the mysql server as for some reason I cannot start the mysql server anymore. Now, the `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1` which should be present in `/var/lib/mysql/` are not there. I can only see `ibdata1` in the folder and my database folders. I have used `InnoDb` engine. So, where are the other possible locations to find the ib_logfile?

Answer (score 1):

Some example where can the log file be is here

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size

The location will probably be under the datadir configuration item, see more here
http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-database-myisam-innodb-1634.html